# APNS <-> FCM token mapping

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, apple-push-notifications, firebase-admin

Is there a way to map APNS token to its corresponding FCM token or vice versa with firebase-admin SDK?

I'm trying to merge an existing messaging system to another that uses FirebaseCloudMessaging.

If a mapping is not possible, is there a way to generate a new FCM token from admin SDK side? Would generating a new FCM token invalidates the existing one?